# Error when creating table with mysqldb module

Tags: python, mysql, database, python-2.7, mysql-python

I'm trying to create a table with 2 columns using python's mysqldb module, but I get an error, what might be wrong here?

```
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE foreign_crew(id VARCHAR(45) PRIMARY_KEY, surname VARCHAR(45))")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 202, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') PRIMARY_KEY, surname VARCHAR(45))' at line 1")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `PRIMARY_KEY` with `PRIMARY KEY`:

```
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE foreign_crew(id VARCHAR(45) PRIMARY KEY, surname VARCHAR(45))")
```

Comment: thanks it worked. but i cant see the foreign_crew table when I open the database in mysql workbench. what is wrong?

Comment: Add `connection.commit()` after the `execute`. `connection` is the result of `mysqldb.connect`.

Comment: i did commit(), but still i cant see it in mysql workbench. is there a refresh button in workbench?